# Coruppted Jenkins need to reinstall

Tags: jenkins

My jenkins looks like corrupted. After installing older version I tried to upgrade. When I tried

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

It was failed to upgrade. Then I removed jenkins using

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins
```

And again I tried to install.It is giving

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jenkins is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjna-java libhttpcore-java libxbean-java libargs4j-java libhttpclient-java
  libplexus-build-api-java libbackport-util-concurrent-java
  libplexus-utils-java libjffi-java libjffi-jni
  libmaven-common-artifact-filters-java libjsr305-java libcommons-jexl-java
  libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-container-default-java
  libganymed-ssh2-java jenkins-cli libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java
  libcommons-net2-java libjsoup-java libmaven2-core-java libplexus-cipher-java
  libjenkins-remoting-java libeasymock-java libplexus-i18n-java
  libmaven-invoker-java libplexus-containers-java libjaffl-java libdoxia-java
  libmaven-dependency-tree-java libmodello-java libplexus-archiver-java
  libconstantine-java libmaven-scm-java libmaven-enforcer-plugin-java
  libplexus-io-java libwagon-java libcommons-vfs-java libanimal-sniffer-java
  libgoogle-collections-java libnetbeans-cvsclient-java
  libmaven-plugin-testing-java libplexus-classworlds-java libitext1-java
  libplexus-interactivity-api-java libcommons-jxpath-java jenkins-common
  libplexus-interpolation-java libclassworlds-java
  libcommons-configuration-java libjnr-posix-java libplexus-ant-factory-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 513 not upgraded.
```

But `service jenkins restart` command throwing

```
jenkins: unrecognized service
```

Even `http://localhost:8080/` not working.

I want to install from beginning . Any suggestions?

**Edited:**

I followed these steps :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then same above steps followed to install.

But still same error.Again I tried to remove package using

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins && sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

This is part of output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 268 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/61.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 67.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
(Reading database ... 224579 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking jenkins (from .../archives/jenkins_1.557_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up jenkins (1.557) ...
```

But still service not recognized.

One more thing I noticed is  `/etc/init.d/jenkins` is empty.

Any other way to install same jenkins package?

Comment: The command to run the jenkins may differ.So post the output of `ls /etc/init.d | grep jen`

Comment: Install jenkins package and then run the above command.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I updated question just now .Please refer additional information. I run command as you suggested.It is giving grep: –: No such file or directory

Comment: First install jenkins package and then post the output of `ls /etc/init.d` command in pastebin.com and finally provide the link here.

Comment: Can you refer my question.I have edited.It is showing like jenkins package installed and command gives : `jenkins
jenkins.dpkg-new`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the package was removed so that is why it is not starting or running. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get autoremove`  In the future take care when installing packages from outside the ubuntu repos. IMO you are better off building from source or using a ppa.

From your description of the problem, your config file was somehow corrupted. simply removing and reinstalling a package will not fix the problem (it rarely does in Linux) because `apt-get remove foo` removes the libs and binary, but leaves the configuration files in place. When you then install `apt-get install foo` the config files remain.

To resolve this problem, IMO it is best to purge rather then remove a package (although if you prefer you can edit the config files to modify the behavior of apt-get).

```
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

If the problem persists you may need to file a bug report against jenkins.

Comment: I tried these steps and again while installing it is giving same problem.Any other way to install same package?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You still have problems if you have packages not upgraded by sudo apt-get dist-upgrade - "268 not upgraded". I am not sure if this is a problem with the version of jenkins you installed or not, but you are likely to have increasing problems moving forward with upgrades and installing packages until you resolve this problem.

Comment: The second problem you seem to have is starting the jenkins server. Again I am not sure if this is a compatibility problem or not. I looked at the jenkins home page and you should have a file "/etc/init.d/jenkins" If you do not , either the documentation is out of date or there is a problem with the package. You may need to file a bug report.

Comment: Please do not keep removing and re-installing the jenkins package, that obviously is not solving the problem and only serves to confuse the issue. First start by installing the package. Then locate the files. `sudo updatedb && locate jenkins` you can pipe the information to a file, paste bin it, or filter it with grep. `locate jenkins | grep init`.

Comment: Now, if I am understanding your comments , the file `/etc/init.d/jenkins` exists, but if empty ? If that is the case you need to try purging and re-installing. `sudo apt-get purge jenkins && sudo apt-get install jenkins`. The difference is purge removes configuration files and remove does not. When you re-install apt-get does not appear to be over-writing /etc/init.d/jenkins. See http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get (apt-get only installs missing config files and will not over write existing or in your case blank files).